# Gnome panel calendar events hard to read in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04, gnome-panel

## The question

When looking at an an event in the box under the calendar in the top-panel flyout, is it supposed to be impossible to see more than two lines describing the event without hovering over it and scrolling?

## Details

The figures show what I see when I click on the date in the top panel and select a day with no event (1st image) or with an event (2nd image). The event description at the bottom fades out before completely showing the time. Furthermore, even the event description is faint compared to the “No Events” description. This is hard to use.

Is this the expected behavior? Is this a bug?

[image: Screenshot of description below calendar in notification panel for a day with no event]

[image: Screenshot of description below calendar in notification panel for a day with an event]

## System

- Ubuntu 22.04.1
- DE: Gnome 42.2
- Session type: Wayland
- Shell: Default (how it is listed in Gnome Tweaks)
- Display size: 13-inch
- Resolution: 3840 x 2160 (native)
- Scaling: 300%
- Fonts

  - Interface text: Ubuntu Regular 10
  - Document text: Sans Regular 12
  - Monospace text: Ubuntu Mono Regular 12
  - Legacy Window Titles: Ubuntu Bold 11
  - Scaling factor: 1
- Machine: Dell XPS 13 9370

Comment: Scaling is 300%.  The higher the scaling value, the less that fits on your screen. I'd guess that if we were to look at a screenshot of your entire screen that this element would take up the amount of space it's designed to take up under those conditions. The design language of GNOME already tends to favor much larger assets and wider margins as compared to other desktop environments. And that's without any scaling. Have you tried a smaller scaling factor like 200%?

Comment: So your take is that it is likely not a bug. It seems like text box size should depend on font size, so it might be worth raising an issue with Gnome, anyway. I have tried 200%. Many UI elements are then too small (and they are too large at 300%, and 250% makes RStudio and Firefox blurry).

Comment: Anything other than 100% or 200% and you get blurring of text and other elements due to the nature of fractional scaling. Any scaling over 100% sacrifices screen real estate. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403864) for an explanation. 200% on a 4K display will  actually render essentially the same as 100% on a FHD display of the same size (the most common screen resolution a large margin). If you need elements to be enlarged without sacrificing screen real estate, another option is to use a screen magnifier.

Comment: Changing the scaling has no effect on this behavior.