# Display parameters on 22.04

Tags: display, 22.04

Is there a way to set display size other than 100% or 200% on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

Below the 100, 200, and 300% option there is an option "fractional scaling" Activate it and you get the option to pick 100 up to 325  increments of 25.

Do take note of the warning underneath it. And if unsure do read  https://askubuntu.com/a/1403864/15811  to understand what you are asking: pixels can not be divided so any other than a perfect matched scaling (ie 100, 200, 300, 400) will have images become less perfect.

[image]