# How to reduce blur from fractional scaling in Xwayland applications in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: gnome, display-resolution, wayland

When I set fractional scaling to 150% every non wayland native apps gets blurry. I installed Firefox deb version it got scaled perfectly but the preinstalled snap version gets blurry.

I **think** only the apps working on X11 and Xwayland are getting blurry. From [this](https://arewewaylandyet.com/) website I installed two apps which the developers were providing by default (like for obs studio it was flatpak and for mpv it was deb package) and they were working fine.

Most of the apps that I use weren't on the list.

How do I fix this blurring issue?

Here is a screenshot comparing Terminal and VLC:
[image]

This one compares Nautilus and VS Code:
[image]

Comment: Are all of the problematic applications snaps? FYI, I've written this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403864) to a similar question which explains why fractional scaling will *always* be blurry compared to no scaling (except for 200% and 400%) However this doesn't address why scaling would be better on some desktops and not GNOME. More information about the problematic applications and what makes them different could be helpful in determining what is the problem.

Comment: Snaps as well as flatpaks.

Comment: And what happens if you don't use the snap? For example, you can test this with Firefox. Snaps and flatpaks are largely isolated from the rest of your system. This has benefits but can also have disadvantages.

Comment: I installed some deb packages like vlc and synaptic both were showing the blurry issue.

Comment: Since we can't see what you can see, please upload images of the problem. Here's exactly what I need to see: First, tell us if the problem shows up in screenshots. If it shows up in screenshots, upload a screenshot that has both a clear and a blurry application in the same image. If the issue does not appear in screenshots, please take a picture of the screen showing both a clear and blurry application in the same photo and upload that image.

Comment: Uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: I think only the apps working on Xwayland are getting blurry, I've edited the question.

Comment: Did you try fully switching to X.Org?